# how array_shift works inside a while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select a table with col1 - col3. I need to eliminate col2 row1 by using array_shift. Here is my code:

```
$data = array(); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result){
     $data[] = $row['time'];
     array_shift($data);

** mytable**
 echo'<tr>'.$data.'<td>';        
}
```

looks like I miss something, it prints nothing in the table. Please advice. Looks like if I use the `array_shift` after the `while loop`, it works but it prints something like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 00:00:05 [1] => 00:00:14 [2] => 00:00:09 [3] => 00:02:24 [4] => 00:01:13 [5] => 00:00:11 [6] => 00:00:09 )
```

It eliminates the first row of the col2 which is what I want, but I dont know how to put it inside the table. Please let me know what I miss...

Comment: Where is `$arr` defined? If you want the first value from an array you need to do something like: `$first = array_shift($my_array);` then you can `echo` `$first`.

Comment: `array_shift($arr)` will Shift an element off the beginning of the array. But what's this `$arr` that you are using?

Comment: @Script47 sorry I edit the code...it should be `$data` thanks

Comment: @A.Kiyoshi do you want it to output the first element of the array?

Comment: You push something in `$data` and then immediately shift it out of the array. How do you expect the array to have anything in it?

Comment: @Script47 I wish to eliminate the first row of the second column of the table.

Comment: You want to keep only the 1st and the 3rd element of the `$data` array, so why don't you just extract theme like `$array = ($data[0], $data[2]);` ?

Comment: @apokryfos can you explain further I dont really understand it...please

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui since I am selecting from a large amount of data, perhaps using that method may work but more coding....what do you think?

Comment: It will helps us if you edit your post and add an example of the input (the result of the sql query) and the desired output.

Comment: @A.Kiyoshi: You are assigning your time to $data[] = "00:00:05"; and after that, you are shifting that value from array_shift($data); in that case, you are not have any output. Because every time you just adding data and flushing out that data using array_shift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just drop the first result and print the array as columns, here's a way to do it (not the best way but it's a logical step from what you already have):

```
$data = array();     
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result){
     $data[] = $row['time'];   
}
array_shift($data);
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($data as $element) {
    echo'<td>'.$element.'</td>';        
}
echo "</tr>"
```

I am assuming you opened a table somewhere above at some point.

Comment: thank you but how do I print other variables who do not need `array_shift`? There will be an error if I print them inside the `while loop` and if I print them inside the `foreach loop` it will only print the first column, and repeat

Comment: Inside the foreach loop you can add additional `echo "<td>Other data</td>;` statements after the first one.